# How to start a process from inittab as specific user?

Tags: linux

I want to make sure one process is immediately started after my server reboots. I added the following line in the `/etc/inittab` file:

```
abc::boot:/xxxxxx/bin/startup.sh
```

But I also need this to start with a certain user `wasadmin`. How can I add this to the line above?

Answer (score 1):

`su -c` and `sudo` are two common commands to run something as different user. They are [somewhat different](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/16335/108618) and the main difference is what password they ask.

Entries from `/etc/inittab` are run by `root` and usually neither `su` nor `sudo` requires password when run as `root`, so the following possibilities are almost equivalent (pick one):

```
abc::boot:su -c '/xxxxxx/bin/startup.sh' wasadmin
abc::boot:sudo -u wasadmin /xxxxxx/bin/startup.sh
```

Notes:

- Since `sudo` access may be restricted (in `/etc/sudoers`) even for the `root` user (although I would find it uncommon), the approach with `su` seems slightly better.
- You may want (need?) to use the full path to `su` (or `sudo`).